# Por que estou recebendo Segmentation fault matriz dinâmica?

Tags: c, alocação

Dizem para não dar cast no retorno da função `malloc`, mas esse código aí se a dimensão da matriz for acima de 4, dá *segmentation fault* a partir de `matriz[5][1]` na contagem:

```
int main(){

    int tamanho = 5;

    float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));

    for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
        *(matriz + i) = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));

    for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tamanho; j++){
            scanf("%f", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Agora se eu der cast, aí funciona de boa. Mas, por que? Se dizem não poder...

Comment: Uma coisa que estou vendo é que no primeiro malloc você está utilizando `sizeof(float)`, quando o correto seria `sizeof(float*)`. Se estiver compilando para 64bits isso faz toda a diferença.

Answer (score 6):

Observe essa linha:

```
float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));
```

Considerando que `tamanho` é 5 e `sizeof(float)` é 4, isso seria:

```
float **matriz = malloc(20);
```

E então aqui, temos isso:

```
for(int i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
    *(matriz + i) = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));
```

Você usa `*(matriz + i)`, ou seja está somando um inteiro com ponteiro, o que não é boa ideia. Isso daí pega o valor do endereço e soma a ele o valor de `i` multiplicado pelo tamanho do tipo referenciado pelo ponteiro, que é `float *`. Considerando que o tamanho do ponteiro seja de 8 bytes, isso vai acessar as posições, 0, 8, 16, 24 e 32. Ao acessar as posições 24 e 32 (e metade da área do 16), você vai estar escrevendo em uma área de memória não alocada, o que pode dar *segmentation fault*.

O problema é que você alocou a matriz com o tamanho errado porque ela é uma matriz de ponteiros, e não uma matriz de `float`s. Ou seja, ao invés disso:

```
float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));
```

Deveria ter colocado isso (observe o `*` a mais):

```
float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float *));
```

E isso faz toda diferença vez que `sizeof(float)` é 4 enquanto que `sizeof(float *)` é 8.

E também, eu recomendo reescrever isso:

```
    *(matriz + i) = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));
```

Assim:

```
    matriz[i] = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Resumindo:

esta linha

```
float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float)); // BAD
```

está errada, deveria ser assim:

```
float **matriz = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(float*)); // GOOD
```

Uma coisa que a maioria dos iniciantes não conseguem entender é que não existem "matrizes" em C, o que parece ser uma "matriz" é na verdade um array de ponteiros.